# Kotlin generic Collection cast

Tags: kotlin

I a very new to Kotlin and working on a simple method that sorts and joins a list to string

```
private fun generateKey(params: Array<Any>): String {
    val genericCollection  = if (params.isNotEmpty() && params[0] is Collection<*>) params[0] as Collection<*>
                    else throw Exception("no params provided for keyGenerator")

    return genericCollection.sortedBy { it }.joinToString(separator = "_")
}
```

but I got this compilation error:

> Type parameter bound for R in
>
> inline fun > Iterable.sortedBy ( crossinline
>   selector: (T) → R? ) : List
>
> is not satisfied: inferred type Any is not a subtype of
>   Comparable

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you try sort this collection via `it`. But `it` can be an instance of any type.
`Any` however isn't something what can be compared (`Any` doesn't implement `Comparable` interface).

So, when you use `sortedBy` method you have to provide something what can be compared. For example:

```
return genericCollection.sortedBy { it.hashCode() }.joinToString(separator = "_")
```

`hashCode()` returns `Int` and `Int` can be easily compared.

In fact until you use `<*>` as generic type you won't be able to find something better to compare collection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
Do you have an idea of a better implementation for this method?

Comment: Use other type. You cannot sort collection without providing information how to do it. How would you sort collection of any type? I mean, not implementation, but what property would you use?

Answer (score 1):

Guess, you must understand, what exactly you expect from param[0]. In this case, it must be some keyGenerator params. Pretty sure, these params could be String or Numeric type. All you need is to map them by casting to appropriate class. Foe example, String class:

```
private fun generateKey(params: Array<Any>): String {
        val genericCollection  = if (params.isNotEmpty() && params[0] is Collection<*>) params[0] as Collection<*>
        else throw Exception("no params provided for keyGenerator")

        return genericCollection.map { it as String }.sortedBy { it }.joinToString(separator = "_")
    }
```